# Covering $n$ points with fewest disks with fixed radius $\epsilon$

Tags: computer-science

The title says it all.  I have a set of $n$ points in $\mathbb{R^{2}}$ and I am looking for an algorithm that tells me the fewest numbers of disks of radius $\epsilon$ that cover the set of $n$ points.  Any ideas?  Has this been done?  I don't need anything incredibly efficient as the sets are not large.

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4705922